# how to send data using FCM without a notification message

Tags: python, django, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM for my app, which uses `Django` as the back end and the front end written by `flutter`.
I can send notifications from my Django app in certain situations and it works as expected. All I need now is to send some data to the flutter app which will behave on it somehow, but without sending a message or notification to the user.

here is how am sending notifications from my Django backend :

```py
from pyfcm import FCMNotification
push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="****")

def send_single_notification(deviceID,title,body):
    try:
        push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="****")
        registration_id = deviceID
        message_title = title
        message_body = body
        result = push_service.notify_single_device(
        registration_id=registration_id, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)
    except:
        print("failed to send notification")

def send_multi_notification(list_of_ids,title,body):
    try:
        registration_ids = list_of_ids
        message_title =title
        message_body = body
        result = push_service.notify_multiple_devices(registration_ids=registration_ids, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)
    except:
        print("failed to send notification")
```

just need to send only data ..

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using [pyfcm](https://pypi.org/project/pyfcm/), in which case you can just send a message without a `message_title` and `message_body` as shown in this example from the documentation:

```
result = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, data_message=data_message, content_available=True)
```